# Is it possible to call a function which internally calls `halt()` without halting my program?

Tags: erlang

I was trying to use a function from a library. The function I am trying to use is calling `erlang:halt()` internally. So it will stop the VM and my program also exits. Is there anyway I can call the this function without exiting my program?

Here is the function trying to call, its from [erlscp](https://github.com/fenollp/erlscp/blob/master/src/erl_compile2.erl#L55). The problem I am facing is nothing executes after this call. I am wondering modifying this library is the only way?

```
-spec compile_cmdline([cmd_line_arg()]) -> no_return().

compile_cmdline(List) ->
    case compile(List) of
    ok -> my_halt(0);
    error -> my_halt(1);
    _ -> my_halt(2)
    end.

-spec my_halt(_) -> no_return().
my_halt(Reason) ->
    erlang:halt(Reason).
```

Comment: The code has been clearly written to only work as a command line tool. You could modify it to export the compile/1 function, and submit a PR to the author to make this an official change.

Comment: Thanks @RichardC. I made changes to export the `compile/1` function and  submitted the PR. It got accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the library is the only way.

You can sometimes use [the meck library](https://github.com/eproxus/meck) or similar tricks to replace a module or individual functions in a module, but that doesn't work for the `erlang` module which is tightly bound to the language itself.

You could try mocking the `my_halt` function instead, but that wouldn't have any effect in this case, since `compile_cmdline` makes a local call to `my_halt`, using `my_halt(0)` instead of `erl_compile2:my_halt(0)`.  Only module-qualified calls to exported functions can be mocked using meck.

Comment: They might try mocking `erl_compile2:my_halt/1`, tho. But it's a private function, so I'm not sure if that will work.

Comment: Yes, since `compile_cmdline` makes a local call to `my_halt`, it will always get the local function definition, regardless of whether it has been mocked.